# Как менять цвета на календаре Android Time Square?

Tags: java, android

Я использую библиотеку Android Time Square календарь. Перерыл все файлы, там ссылается R. А там нельзя менять да и как hex менять... Вопрос как изменить цвета, тексты на Android Time Square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотри на какие ресурсы они ссылаются и переопредели их в своих ресурсах. Чтобы переопрделить ресурс нужно просто создать его с таким же именем, но другим значением

Comment: Как же сам не догадался)) Спасибо!!!